# spring-data-neo4j remove nodeEntity and all referenced nodes

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I've got a simple graph model: **1** `User` has **N** `SocialUser`.

I'm wondering if there is any way through `spring-data-neo4j` to automatically delete all `SocialUser` referenced when I remove an `User` entity.

This is what I've got so far:

**Domain:**

```
@NodeEntity
public class User implements IdentifiableEntity<String> {

   @GraphId
   private Long nodeId;
   // ...

   @RelatedTo(type = "HAS", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
   Set<SocialUser> socialUsers = new HashSet<>();
}

@NodeEntity
public class SocialUser implements BasicNodeEntity {

   @GraphId
   private Long nodeId;
   //...

   @RelatedTo(type = "HAS", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
   User user;
}
```

**Data**:

[image: After insert]

**What I've tried:**

- Delete a user through [GraphRepository](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/3.1.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/repository/GraphRepository.html)
- Delete a user through [Neo4jTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/3.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/template/Neo4jOperations.html)

In both cases, only `User` is deleted:

[image]

At the moment I've encapsulated the deletion of both entities in a `@Transactional` method in the `User` service. Something like this:

```
   @Autowired
   Neo4jOperations template;

   @Transactional
   public void delete(String userId) throws Exception {
      User user = get(userId);
      if (user == null) throw new ResourceNotFoundException("user not found");
      Set<SocialUser> socialUsers = template.fetch(user.getSocialUsers());
      for (SocialUser socialUser : socialUsers) template.delete(socialUser);
      userRepository.delete(user);
   }
```

But I'm thinking it's probably not the best way to achieve it. Also I've thought that it could be better to directly execute a `Cypher` statement to delete all referenced nodes..

Anyone can advise me how to deal with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I know it has been a while, but I am in the same place. Did you come up with a cleaner solution?

Comment: Hi @Ceekay. Not yet, at the moment I'm doing in the same way that I post in my question. If you find a better choice, you could post an aswer. Thanks

Comment: @Ceekay, After being a time working on it, I think the best choice is to use a cypher query. See my answer for more info. Hope it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's been a while, but after being a time working with `SDN` and `neo4j`, it seems to be that the best way to accomplish this is using a `Cypher` query.

```
MATCH (user:User{id:'userId'})-[has:HAS]->(socialUser:SocialUser)
DELETE user, has, socialUser
```

With SDN, we can take advantadge of repositores:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends Neo4jRepository<User> {

    @Query("MATCH (user:User{id:{id}})-[has:HAS]->(socialUser:SocialUser) DELETE user, has, socialUser")
    void delete(String id);
}
```

Hope it helps other people

Comment: You should mark this as the answer I think that is a clean way of solving this problem.

Comment: Done! Thanks @Ceekay