# What is the correct way to update the graph containing delete of nodes through spring data neo4j?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Have a simple structure like this.

```
@Data
public class DomainObject {
    @GraphId
    protected Long id;
    public String createdBy;
    public Date createdTS;
    public String lstModBy;
    public Date lstModTS;
}

@NodeEntity(label = "StepDef")
@Data
public class StepDef extends DomainObject{
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String catCode;
    private String impClass;
    private String scope;
    @Relationship(type = "PROPERTY_OF" = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<StepDefProperty> properties;
}

@NodeEntity(label = "StepDefProperty")
@Data
public class StepDefProperty extends DomainObject{
        private String key;
        private String value;
        private String type;
        private String lookupKey;
}
```

When I try to add the StepDefProperty objects to the properties list and use the stepRepo.save(stepDef) it saves perfectly as expected along with the relationship.

[image]

The issue is when deleting one of the properties node. So if I remove one of the property node from the list and use repo.save(stepDef) the property node is not removed.
I thought this could be something to do with the inconsistent session.
So I tried doing a stepRepo.findOne(stepDef.getId()) before doing the repo.save(stepDef)
Now this removes the relationship between the nodes, however the property node is still present in the database as an orphan, while expected the property node along with the relationship to be deleted.
[image]
What is the right way of doing updates through spring data neo4j?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130275/spring-data-neo4j-remove-nodeentity-and-all-referenced-nodes/40136479#40136479) help you?

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely using the API correctly when it comes to disassociating the relationship between the `StepDef` node and the `StepDefProperty` relations.

The problem is you haven't told the OGM `Session` that you want to also delete the node on the other end of the removed relationship.

So what you need to do is retrieve the property node to be deleted as well as removing it from the collection in `StepDef`. You can then call `repo.delete(StepDefPropertyToBeDeleted)` and `repo.save(stepDef)` and everything will work out the way you intend.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this would mean that I would have to manually keep track of the node to be deleted rather than the framework doing it. Would have hoped spring data would handled it for me.

Comment: In what other framework would you expect the entity to be deleted though? If the domain object is well encapsulated it should be pretty easy to get the object that is going to be deleted.

Comment: (Sorry for digging out this old Thread) e.g. Hibernate provides a property for its relational annotations with the name "orphanRemoval" wich has exactly the wanted behaviour: Remove Entities that have lost the relation to the saved Entity (e.g. on save of the Parent-Entity). Does spring-data-neo4j have something like this in its newest versions? This would reduce a lot of boilerplate-code (for deleting orphans)